# Drag File in Data URI format from Browser to Desktop

Tags: javascript, html

As [this blog post](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-dragout) points out, there is a way to download files via drag and drop from browser to desktop.

I want to drag a file in data uri format (e.g. "data:application/octet-stream;base64,eNcoDEdFiLEStuFf") to the desktop. I cannot provide a full URL to a server download due to security reasons (file needs to be handled clientside).

When I try what's given in the example of the blog post, a file which content and name is the current timestamp is created:

```
item.addEventListener("dragstart", function(evt) {
    evt.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", "data:application/octet-stream;base64,eNcoDEdFiLEStuFf");
}
```

I already tried changing the format parameter, tweaking the format of the data a little and deconding beforehand but nothing works, I never get any of my data onto my desktop. Is there any way to accomplish what I am looking for, at least in some browsers?

By the way, we do not use jQuery. As a result, it might be interesting if there is a solution with jQuery but this will most probably not be applicable for our project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far i understood download URL should have following format:
mime-type:file_name:URL. Were URL is your data URI.
For your case:

```
item.addEventListener("dragstart", function(evt) {
    evt.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", "application/octet-stream:fileName.bin:data:application/octet-stream;base64,eNcoDEdFiLEStuFf");
}
```

Which should create fileName.bin file.

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Andrei_Yanovich/jqym7wdh/
But it looks like it works only in chrome

Comment: I also tried that one, did not work... created the same "timestamp-file" as the other ways

Comment: Okay, I re-checked your jsfiddle and my code. While this is definitely working the way you do it, it isn't in my code but that is my problem :( for everyone else encountering this: I am using an asynchronous call during dragstart and calling evt.dataTransfer.setData() in its response. It seems, that this function can only be called at the beginning of the event handler.