# HTML drag/drop - how to set the filename of an *outgoing* drag (to desktop)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make it so a user can drag an icon from the web browser to their desktop, and a text file is created. I've got the content part down, but I can't figure out how to set the filename. I've tried mutating `dataTransfer.files` but that's read-only. I'm not sure how to achieve this.

```
class CrashReport extends React.Component {
  dragStart(event) {
    const dat = {name: 'test!', crashDate: new Date()};

    event.dataTransfer.name = 'tmp.txt'; // bad
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', JSON.stringify(dat, null, 2));
    console.log(event.dataTransfer);
  }

  render() {
    return <div draggable onDragStart={this.dragStart.bind(this)}>
      Drag This
    </div>
  }
}
```

http://embed.plnkr.co/ar3deFFvedcWhVfwt6c6/

Comment: _"I've got the content part down"_ Can you create a stacksnippets or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: @guest271314 The code above does exactly that (drag/drop to desktop, a file is created). I'll add a Plunker link.

Comment: No file is created here at plnkr by dragging to desktop, only when dragging element at plnkr to a file manager is a _link_ to file created; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416748/drag-a-file-from-browser-to-desktop?rq=1#comment53385290_5416795. Though using this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343897/drag-file-in-data-uri-format-from-browser-to-desktop you can set the link to file name by setting `.innerHTML` of for example an `<a>` element that is dragged to file manager.

Comment: Have you considered using put_file_contents or fwrite & fopen ? You can write a script in PHP and call it using AJAX because javascript has nothing to do with local or server files( its not server side friendly )

Comment: @TheBumpaster That sounds like server-side code.

Comment: @guest271314 Please post an answer ASAP (the bounty period is about to end) - your link (the second one) is what pointed me in the right direction to at least get it working in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Recommended_Drag_Types#file) <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

> A local file is dragged using the `application/x-moz-file` type with a data value that is an [nsIFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFile) object. **Non-privileged web pages are not able to retrieve or modify data of this type.**

So, if you're not writing a browser extension, you can't, and will receive a `Security Error`.

What happens when you drag some data to the Desktop is up to your OS (mine converts it to some `.textClipping` file format).

Answer (score 2):

Argh! The below works fine in Chrome:

```
const jsonData = JSON.stringify(dat);
event.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", "application/json:crashdump.json:data:application/json;charset=utf-8," + jsonData);
```

Though not in Safari nor Firefox. What a huge bummer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.innerHTML` of an `<a>` element to set the name of linked file

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Drag out any of these links to your dekstop</h1>
  <a href="file.txt" id="dragout" class="dragme" draggable="true">file.txt</a>    
</div>
```

where `file.txt` is a local file dragged into file manager at *nix os which creates a `Link to file.txt`.

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/pif0ZraAn9RbJI8w2z0w?p=preview

See also [Drag File in Data URI format from Browser to Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343897/drag-file-in-data-uri-format-from-browser-to-desktop)

Answer (score -3):

You can write

```
event.dataTransfer.setData = ('text', 'tmp.txt');
```

Comment: No offense to him, but I think Sandip needs to learn JavaScript. ;)

Comment: @ffxsam : can you please let me know what is wrong in that so I can correct my mistake.

Comment: Sure. `event.dataTransfer.setData` is a method. You’re setting a method to equal something else (which, BTW, is apparently valid JS syntax, but I’ve never seen it before).