# Drag and drop generated content from chrome 62 to desktop

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, data-uri

I'm am working on an interactive content editing system.
In the system, you should be able to freely drag and drop content between the website and your desktop. I use the html5 drag and drop API. Dragging files with a persistent url onto desktop works.
However, dragging dynamically-generated content (e.g. some string value) is not working for me (in latest chrome, version 62).

I already tried two possibilities I stumbled upon while researching this issue. Both solutions seem outdated:

- The first one is using a **data url** to encode the dynamic content:

```js
const span = document.querySelector("#drag");

span.addEventListener("dragstart", evt => {
  const mimeType = 'text/plain';
  const filename = 'example.txt';
  const content = 'someDynamicContent';
  // using data url:
  const url =  `data:text/plain;base64,${btoa(content)}`;

  evt.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", `${mimeType}:${filename}:${url}`);
})
```

```css
#drag {
  user-select: none;
  user-drag: element;
}
```

```html
<span id="drag" draggable="true">Drag me onto Desktop</span>
```

I'm aware of a very similar, yet old, question ([Drag File in Data URI format from Browser to Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343897/drag-file-in-data-uri-format-from-browser-to-desktop)). The provided answer seems to be outdated and does not work in (at least) chrome 62 anymore.

- The second one uses **URL.createObjectURL** to create a temporary url to use as a DownloadURL.

```js
const span = document.querySelector("#drag");

span.addEventListener("dragstart", evt => {
  const mimeType = 'text/plain';
  const filename = 'example.txt';
  const content = 'someDynamicContent';
  // using createObjectURL:
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([content], {type : 'text/plain'}));

  evt.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", `${mimeType}:${filename}:${url}`);
});
```

```css
#drag {
  user-select: none;
  user-drag: element;
}
```

```html
<span id="drag" draggable="true">Drag me onto Desktop</span>
```

So the question is, how to perform a drag operation, that gives you a file with the provided content (and not just some link to the Blob's url) on your desktop?

(The proposed solution only needs to work in chrome)

Comment: trying to do the same... still no results :(